# Most effective way to get the methods of any collider object in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a bullet game object that detects enemies via `OnTriggerEnter2D()`. This was working perfectly until I added different enemy types:

```
private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
    {
        Enemy enemy = collision.GetComponent<Enemy>();
        if (enemy != null)
        {
            enemy.Destroy();
            GameObject effect_ = Instantiate(bulletEffect, transform.position, transform.rotation);
            Destroy(effect_, 0.5f);
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }

    }
```

So simply if the bullet collides with `Enemy()` then it should call its `Destroy()` method.

The problem is that now I have added multiple enemies in my game, for example there is an enemy with the class name `Runner()` with its own death method.

I can add an if condition and cycle through every enemy type but that will become tedious after more enemies are added.

Whats the best way of doing this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a script called 'DamageBehavior'. Give that script a public function called 'TakeDamage'. Attach that script to each type
of enemy so that they may each implement it differently. Then in your OnTriggerEnter2D function, regardless of the type of enemy 
that's been collided with, call its TakeDamage function.

```
private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
{
   if (other.CompareTag("Enemy"))
    {
        other.GetComponent<DamageBehavior>().TakeDamage();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this would work but I want to keep all enemies under the ``Enemy`` umbrella tag. Is there a way to do this without assigning new tags to every enemy?

Comment: @StuckInPhD I don't suppose each type of enemy gameObject has its own unique name they can be identified by? If not, what you can do is create a bunch of 'if/ else if' statements to see if the enemy that's been collided with has a certain script, and if it does, execute the appropriate functions. But that isn't good game design. Neither is the answer that I previously posted about using tags. The more types of enemies you add, the more if statements you have to go back and add to your OnTrigger function. I've edited my previous answer to give you a much better solution.

Answer (score 4):

## Why not let the enemy decide what happens?

```
private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
{
    Enemy enemy = collision.GetComponent<Enemy>();
    if (enemy != null)
    {
       enemy.DoDeathEffects(); //you will need to create this function.
       Destroy(gameObject);
    }
}
```

Your *bullet* should never decide what an enemy does when it does, that's the purview of *the enemy.* As you want your various enemies to have different behaviors, this means you will need to *subclass* the `Enemy` class and the `DoDeathEffects()` method should be both `public` and `virtual`.

Comment: Sorry, I think you misunderstood. I dont want my bullet to decide what to do, what I'm asking is how to get the respective class? For example ``Enemy enemy = collision.GetComponent<Enemy>();`` wont work on every enemy, as some enemies would work with: ``Runner runner = collision.GetComponent<Runner>();`` How do I get around this? The other answer gets what I want to do, but I dont want to assign a different tag to every enemy type.

Comment: If you can't use `GetComponent<E>();` (for some class `E`) the you aren't using inheritance properly. *All* of your enemies should share some common super-class or interface that allows you to call a single known function when a bullet collides with them. Your accepted answer uses `DamageBehavior` and the third answer uses `IDeath`

Answer (score 0):

If all your enemies inherit from the same base class, make the death method virtual, and override it in child classes.

Alternative is to create an interface, and make your components implement that interface

```
interface IDeath
{
 void OnDeath();
}
```

than when the collision happens you can do GetComponent< IDeath >() and get a reference to an object that does have this method, even if it doesnt inherit from anything (well it needs to inherit MonoBehaviour but thats it)